# SQL Finding the first event and then the closing event after it

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write some SQL query, but no luck so far.
I would like to receive the event_start and event_end for each event (There is no event_id, unfortunately!) in the example

input

| event_timestamp | event_date | customer_ID | event_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-07 16:18:18.000000 | 2021-02-07 | 1234567 | event_start |
| 2021-02-07 16:34:44.000000 | 2021-02-07 | 1234567 | event_end |
| 2021-02-07 16:49:08.000000 | 2021-02-07 | 1234567 | event_start |
| 2021-02-07 17:04:35.000000 | 2021-02-07 | 1234567 | event_end |
| 2021-02-07 17:19:46.000000 | 2021-02-07 | 1234567 | event_start |
| 2020-09-28 09:37:09.000000 | 2020-09-28 | 7654321 | event_start |
| 2020-09-28 09:52:08.000000 | 2020-09-28 | 7654321 | event_start |
| 2020-09-28 13:15:17.000000 | 2020-09-28 | 7654321 | event_end |

the logic is as follows:

- if the event_end is right after the event_start then receive the timestamp for event_start as start and the timestamp for the following event_end as an end
- if there are multiple event_starts before an event_end then receive the timestamp for the FIRST event_start as start and the timestamp for the event_end which closes this cycle of event_starts
- if there is an event_start without and event_end after it (for the specified day and ID) then the event_end = 23:59:59 the same day as it will expire at night

I think I should use some kind of window function, but it seems like I cant figure out what and how exactly!

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Basically the new table should look like this:

| customer_ID | event_date | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567 | 2021-02-07 | 2021-02-07 16:18:18.000000 | 2021-02-07 16:34:44.000000 |
| 1234567 | 2021-02-07 | 2021-02-07 16:49:08.000000 | 2021-02-07 17:04:35.000000 |
| 1234567 | 2021-02-07 | 2021-02-07 17:19:46.000000 | 2021-02-07 23:59:59.000000 |
| 7654321 | 2020-09-28 | 2020-09-28 09:37:09.000000 | 2020-09-28 13:15:17.000000 |

Comment: Could you put your input and result into the question as text, rather than linked images? It's very hard to do anything with images.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: sorry guys, first time.. I hope its better now

Answer (score 0):

My honest opinion is to fix the data model...  find some way to designate a distinct event.  I think you can come up with hacks, but I find it hard to believe you can ever find a hack that is bulletproof enough to withstand the possibilities of unstructured data.

That said, in the spirit of trying to help, here is such a hack.  In effect, I am trying to guess at what binds two records together by creating an artificial event_id (in the `event_data` CTE).  Assuming that was done correctly, the second part should be pretty effective.

```
with event_data as (
  select
    event_timestamp, event_date, customer_id, event_name,
    sum (1) filter (where event_name = 'event_start') 
        over (partition by customer_id order by event_timestamp) as event_id 
  from events
)
select
  e1.event_id, e1.customer_id, e1.event_date,
  e1.event_timestamp as start,
  coalesce (e2.event_timestamp, date_trunc ('day', e1.event_timestamp) + interval '23:59:59') as end
from
  event_data e1
  left join event_data e2 on
    e1.customer_id = e2.customer_id and
    e1.event_id = e2.event_id and
    e2.event_name = 'event_end'
where
  e1.event_name = 'event_start'
```

The results don't match your resulting dataset exactly, but when you see the output it may give ideas on why that is so...  and you might even agree with the modified output.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am using Redshift. I should have mentioned that, but anyway sum (1) filter (where event_name = 'event_start') ` is not working, but I got your idea. The best way will be indeed to structure the data, which is basically the hard part.Thanks